# Why does network ad URL from SO to history.SE mention Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: bug, advertising

Today, I was on Stack Overflow when I noticed an interesting ad pointing to history.SE (actual square ad, not just Hot Network Questions).

The link in the ad was:

http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI6NDE0LCJhdCI6MTcsImJ0IjowLCJjbSI6OTkzLCJjaCI6MTE3OCwiY2siOnt9LCJjciI6MjY2MywiZGkiOiIzZjlmZWQxYTViOWY0OGJkYTNhOTNlNDg5MjU5NjEwYSIsImRtIjoxLCJmYyI6MTE3MTgsImZsIjoyODQxLCJpcCI6Ijc4LjEyOC4xOTcuNDIiLCJrdyI6ImMsdmlzdWFsLXN0dWRpby0yMDEwLGxpYnhtbDIseC11c2VyLXJlZ2lzdGVyZWQseC11c2VyLWhpZ2hyZXAiLCJudyI6MjIsInBjIjowLCJwciI6MTYwNCwicnQiOjEsInJmIjoiaHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy80ODAyMjA1L2lzLXRoZXJlLWEtd2F5LXRvLWZpbmQtYW5kLXJlcGxhY2UtdGhlLXRleHQtdmFsdWUtYmV0d2Vlbi1ub2Rlcy1vZi1hLWNvcnJ1cHQteG0_cnE9MSIsInN0Ijo4Mjc3LCJ1ayI6InVlMS0yODBiNzk0ZjViOWU0YmJhYTJiYjc5OGUwNmM5MjA4NiIsInpuIjo0NSwidHMiOjE0Mzk0MDkwNDY4MDEsImJmIjp0cnVlLCJwbiI6ImFkemVyazEzMjczNzI3MDUiLCJ1ciI6bnVsbH0&s=ep5sb5AD5V2i7PRO9nk1EqWRnB0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhistory.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F23946%2Fwhat-were-greek-and-roman-sails-made-from%3Futm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3Dhttp-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te%26utm_campaign%3Dhistory.stackexchange.com-promo%26utm_content%3D23946

which resolves to:

`https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23946/what-were-greek-and-roman-sails-made-from?utm_medium=ad&utm_source=http-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te&utm_campaign=history.stackexchange.com-promo&utm_content=23946`

(link form for conveniece: [What were Greek and Roman sails made from?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23946/what-were-greek-and-roman-sails-made-from?utm_medium=ad&utm_source=http-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te&utm_campaign=history.stackexchange.com-promo&utm_content=23946))

The confusing part os the URL is: `utm_source=http-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te`. The ad is from SO to history.SE, it doesn't have anything to do with Ask Ubuntu, so why does it appear in the URL? Is this a bug?

**EDIT:** Okay, managed to trigger it again: the page [C# Unions of Structs that Contain Arrays of Structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975876/c-sharp-unions-of-structs-that-contain-arrays-of-structs) contains this ad:

[image]

The link of the ad is:

http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=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&s=AjfMUO0JF9RrEUWaIqJzs_TobJs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopensource.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F1556%2Fhow-to-react-to-unhelpful-contributions-to-otherwise-unnoticed-projects%3Futm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3Dhttp-sharepoint-stackexchange-com-questions-16925-why-am-i-getting-server-erro%26utm_campaign%3Dopensource.stackexchange.com-promo%26utm_content%3D1556

which resolves to:

`http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/how-to-react-to-unhelpful-contributions-to-otherwise-unnoticed-projects?utm_medium=ad&utm_source=http-sharepoint-stackexchange-com-questions-16925-why-am-i-getting-server-erro&utm_campaign=opensource.stackexchange.com-promo&utm_content=1556`

incorrectly referencing an unrelated sharepoint.SE question.

Comment: Could you please share the two points listed under "Points to note here:" in my answer.

Comment: I *think* the question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263397/how-to-pass-all-the-xml-files-located-in-one-folder-to-libxml-for-parsing?rq=1. But I can't get any network ad to show for me on SO right now, so I can't repeat it.

Comment: Thanks but it's going to be hard to reproduce as these square ads are displayed randomly... I tried 5-6 refresh but no luck. Also, do you remember if u read the post  http://askubuntu.com/questions/471178/converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-terminal

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't read it.

Comment: Thanks. Now if you are  _pretty sure_ then it definitely makes this a _bug_. We will have to wait for official answer from SE's team. They can surely trace this by looking at the promo ad logs (impressions) that were served on SO today.

Comment: @HackerKarma It happened again, see edit.

Comment: +1 for the screenshot and ad link. I have updated my answer. Please see my update under EDIT section

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP's statement: (emphasis mine)

> Today, I was on **Stack Overflow** when I noticed an interesting ad
>   **pointing to history.SE** (actual square ad, not just Hot Network
>   Questions).

Then, this is definitely a **bug**. Here is why.

Just out of curiosity, I visited to the post [Converting hundreds of jpg to PDF using Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471178/converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-terminal) (obtained from OP's post: `utm_source=http-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te`) and I saw a square box ad (just like what OP saw on Stack Overflow) pointing to mathematica.SE

Here is the screenshot of it:

> [image]

The link and the parameters of the ad:

> http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=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&s=hu5xoK32sVqo8UStlDDpDy4JEHk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathematica.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F91400%2Fplotting-a-sequence-isosceles-triangles-of-diminishing-size%3Futm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3Dhttp-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te%26utm_campaign%3Dmathematica.stackexchange.com-promo%26utm_content%3D91400

In the above ad link:

- **utm_source** is set to `http-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te` This is to track the *source* that is sending the visits. In this case it is *correctly* set to the URL of the post where I am *currently* on.
- **utm_campaign** is set to `mathematica.stackexchange.com-promo` which identifies a specific product promotion i.e. *mathemetica* in this case.

So, if we apply the same logic to OP's given ad link then **utm_source** *has* to be the **Stack Overflow URL** where OP saw the square box ad. But, as per the OP's given example:

**utm_source** is set to `http-askubuntu-com-questions-471178-converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-te` which is a question from the AskUbuntu.com domain and *not* from StackOverflow.com

<s>**Points to note here:**</s>

1. OP has *not* shared the SO *URL* where he saw the square box ad pointing to history.SE
2. OP did *not* took the *screenshot* of the page (like I did for the ad)

I wish these two things were provided by OP. The *only* thing we have here from OP is the *ad link* shared in the answer. Based on the OP's shared ad link's *utm_source* and if OP says he was on Stack Overflow website, then this is definitely a ***bug***.

But, If I *just* consider the *utm_source* in the OP's ad link then OP has to be on the Ask Ubuntu question: [Converting hundreds of jpg to PDF using Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471178/converting-hundreds-of-jpg-to-pdf-using-terminal)

**EDIT:**  (for OP's newly share screenshot and the ad link)

After my comment asking for evidence of any screenshot, OP did manage to reproduced it for an another ad (i.e. Opensource) on the Stack Overflow website. As per the OP's edit and the shared ad link it shows:

**utm_source** set to `http-sharepoint-stackexchange-com-questions-16925-why-am-i-getting-server-erro` which is from the Sharepoint.SE domain instead of StackOverflow.com domain.

This is definitely a '**bug**'.

**P.S.**

Upon doing 'View Page Source' I see the following code that dynamically generates/creates the square box ad: (sample code is grabbed from one of the ad shown on SO)

`<script> 
var ados = ados || {}; ados.run = ados.run || []; ados.run.push(function () { ados_add_placement(22,8277,"adzerk2024591814",[17,2221]).setZone(45); });
</script> 
<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow" id="adzerk2024591814">`

So, when the function makes a call (AJAX) to create a dynamic ad, Adzerk server knows where the call is coming from. It would be great to know what these parameters are actually for and what they do.